# Inverse of operators norm

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, normed-spaces

Could someone help  me to prove this inequality and decide if it can be an equality?

Let be T a lineal isomorphism between $ (X,||·||) (Y,||·||)$  prove that $||T^{-1}||\geq||T||^{-1}$.

Thanks.

Comment: When $X$ and $Y$ are Hilbert spaces, then you have equality if and only if $T^*T$ is a multiple of the identity, which is the same as saying that there exists $a > 0$ such that $\|Tx\| = a\|x\|$ for all $x\in X$.

Comment: Sorry, what is $T^{*}$?

Comment: It is the adjoint of $T$. But when you have not yet considered Hilbert spaces and operators between them in class, never mind.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We have $1 = \|\operatorname{Id}\| = \|T^{-1}\circ T\| \leqslant \|T^{-1}\| \cdot \|T\|$ and therefore $\|T^{-1}\| \geqslant \|T\|^{-1}$.

However, in general the equality doesn’t hold. Take, for instance, $X = Y = \mathbb{R}^2$ with its usual norm. Define $T \colon \mathbb{R}^2\longrightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ by $T(x,y) = (2x,y)$. In such case, $\|T\| = 2$ and $\|T^{-1}\| = 1$.

Comment: How could you take the inverse of a vector $T\in R^2$?

Comment: Since $T$ is an operator, not a vector, I don't understand your question.