# If $T$ is linear and bounded and $T^{-1}$ exists and is also bounded then $\|T\|^{-1} \leq \|T^{-1}\|$

Tags: functional-analysis, solution-verification

> If $T$ is linear and bounded and $T^{-1}$ exists and is also bounded then $\|T\|^{-1} \leq \|T^{-1}\|$

Now, this has been proven [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2467313/inverse-of-operators-norm) but I wonder if my proof is correct too:

$\|T\|^{-1} = \sup_{x\in X, x \neq 0}\frac{\|x\|_x}{\|Tx\|_y} = \sup_{x\in X, x \neq 0}\frac{\|T^{-1}(T(x))\|_x}{\|Tx\|_y} \leq \sup_{x\in X, x \neq 0}\frac{\|T^{-1}\|\|Tx\|_y}{\|Tx\|_y} = \|T^{-1}\|$
where I used the fact that for all linear bounded operators $S$ we have $\|Sx\|_y \leq \|S\|\|x\|_x$.

What worries me is that I don't know if $\| Tx\|_y$ is not zero (but I act as if I knew that). Is that correct?

Comment: If $T^{-1}$ exists then $Tx=0$ if and only if $x=0$.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy is that something trivial to prove?

Comment: Of course it is trivial. $T$  invertible implies that $T$ is one-to-one.